# Mysql rows into columns, optimization query using IF

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have this following query:

```
SELECT a.rank AS rank, concat( m.prenom, ' ', m.nom ) AS name, d.department
FROM `0_area` AS a
LEFT JOIN 0_member AS m ON a.user_id = m.id
LEFT JOIN 0_depart AS d ON a.user_id = d.user_id
WHERE a.sec_id = 2
AND (a.rank = 'mod' OR a.rank = 'adm')
AND d.department IN ( 75, 92 )
```

The above query is returning me three columns, naming `rank | name | department` and it's working, with a separate row for each rank against a department.

```
rank | name | department

mod  |  Steven Smith   |  75   
mod  |  Jeremy Roy     |  92  
adm  |  Vincent Jones  |  75
```

What I need, is to get all those information in one row, because I need to have it as a part of another bigger query, that is returning one row only.

I thought of group_concat, and to have two columns, one for mod and one for adm. In case there are multiple mods (in 75, 92 for the given example), they will be comma separated.

```
mod  | adm   

Steven Smith, Jeremy Roy   |  Vincent Jones
```

Have I been clear? Thanks friends.

Comment: group concat the names of people instead.

Comment: Thanks @ToonMariner, but even that way, I am getting two rows. I wanted to have one row. What do you think?

Comment: if this is to be part of a bigger query it may help if you elaborate on that as it may be easier to NOT group this data at this stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some googling told me that I need this sql:

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT( if( a.rank='mod', concat( m.prenom, ' ', m.nom ), '' ) ) AS 'mod', 
GROUP_CONCAT( if( a.rank='adm', concat( m.prenom, ' ', m.nom ), '' ) ) AS 'adm'
FROM `0_area` AS a
LEFT JOIN 0_member AS m ON a.user_id = m.id
LEFT JOIN 0_depart AS d ON a.user_id = d.user_id
WHERE a.sec_id =2
AND (a.rank = 'mod' OR a.rank = 'adm' )
AND d.department IN ( 75, 92 )
GROUP BY a.sec_id
```

@ToonMariner This solves the problem for this query, however, I will still need to put two queries together. Probably I will create a new post for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT
    a.rank AS rank,
    concat( m.prenom, ' ', m.nom ) AS name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(d.department ORDER BY d.department ASC SEPARATOR '|')
FROM
    `0_area` AS a
LEFT JOIN
    0_member AS m
ON
    a.user_id = m.id
LEFT JOIN
    0_depart AS d
ON
    a.user_id = d.user_id
WHERE
    a.sec_id = 2
AND
    (a.rank = 'mod' OR a.rank = 'adm')
AND
    d.department IN ( 75, 92 )
GROUP BY
    a.rank
```

Comment: Would the separator be the default of ',' and not '|' ?

Comment: Thanks @ToonMariner. I have updated my question, probably I was not clear enough earlier.

Comment: @Steve Claridge Well I don't really care the separator, ',' or '|'